# How to do a GWT-Wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, jsni

Hi i need some guidance or pointer of how to do a wrapper of a javascript library.

I make a simple javascript "myTest.js" with a function:

```
function myFunction(num)
{
    if(num==1){
        return "Hello World1!";
    }else{
        return "bye World2!";
    }
}
```

And the i called in my simple HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" SRC="myLib.js">  

</script>
    <title>Tutorial: HelloWorld</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example HTML</h1>
    <input type="button" value="button" onclick="alert(myFunction(1))">
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously this example is very easy to do in GWT.

This is only to i learn how do i do a gwt-wrapper of the javascript file to be able to call the function in GWT.

Thanks

---

ok, i need a more powerfull example if i have an js file with this function:

```
  function MyObject() {
    // properties in config
    this.displayname = 'First Last';
    this.username = '1060';
    this.domain = '12.18.34.234';
    this.authname =  '1060';
    this.password = '1060';
    this.transport = 'w34s';
   }
```

and in html is script part i made this call

```
var myObj = new MyObject();
```

how do i make this in GWT??

do i have to create the class MyObject?
with the fields presented in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call native javascript in GWT you can define a native method in your GWT class like this:

```
private native void test(String argument)/*-{
    myFunction(argument);
}-*/
```

When you call the method test("foo") from GWT it will call the native js function myFunction("foo");

Answer (score 2):

To bridge between Java and JavaScript types, make use of GWT's [overlay types](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay?hl=iw) to create an API wrapping layer.

Than you can create a separate [module](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects?hl=iw#DevGuideModules) to contain the wrapped library and link it to the main module.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSNI. See the documentation for GWT 2.4 [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI).

Answer (score 0):

Right now you should use JSNI but there's also js interop. js interop makes things  a lot easier and in 2.8 which is coming very soon js interop will be the norm and it'll be built right into the GWT compiler. They say js interop in 2.7 is experimental though. [here's](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-api-interop/w/list) the documentation on it.